# TensorFlow AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled

Tags: tensorflow, keras, runtime-error, tensorflow2.0

I have not a very complicated model for MNIST recognition, playing with its architecture and trying to visualize what is happening inside. After I have added variable for turning off some parts of the network (towerWeights…), I started getting error when trying to get gradients of a layer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VisQtMain.py", line 1021, in onGradientsByImagesPressed
    dataList.append(self.netWrapper.getGradients(layerName, imageNum, 1, epochNum, True))
  File "E:\Projects\Python\Visualiz_Zeiler\MnistNetVisWrapper.py", line 241, in getGradients
    outputs=self.gradientTensors)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3009, in function
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3758, in function
    return EagerExecutionFunction(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3655, in __init__
    base_graph=source_graph)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\lift_to_graph.py", line 249, in lift_to_graph
    visited_ops = set([x.op for x in sources])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\lift_to_graph.py", line 249, in <listcomp>
    visited_ops = set([x.op for x in sources])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 559, in op
    return self._handle.op
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1098, in op
    "Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.")
AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.
```

The network is like

```
inputs = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

conv_1 = Conv2D(16, 5, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', name='conv_1_common')(inputs)

towerWeightsKerasVar = tf.compat.v1.Variable(np.ones([4]), dtype=tf.float32, name='tower_weights')
# towerWeightsKerasVar._trainable = False
**towerWeights = Input(shape=(4, ), tensor=towerWeightsKerasVar)**
…
dense_2 = Dropout(0.3)(conv _1)
dense_2 = Dense(10, name='dense_2')(dense_2)
prediction = Activation("softmax", name="softmax")(dense_2)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs, towerWeights], outputs=prediction)
```

and it can be reproduced on this cut variant. TensorFlow 2.0 RC, 2.0.0 and today tf-nightly – result is the same. **Is it a bug in TF or am I doing something wrong?**

TowerWeights is used for multiplying some parts of network by its components. But in the cut variant it just exists and doing nothing.

I don’t understand well enough what is happening, were eager mode is working, where it is not. I tried to disable eager execution with tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution(), 
but then I am getting

```
  File "VisQtMain.py", line 1021, in onGradientsByImagesPressed
    dataList.append(self.netWrapper.getGradients(layerName, imageNum, 1, epochNum, True))
  File "E:\Projects\Python\Visualiz_Zeiler\MnistNetVisWrapper.py", line 246, in getGradients
    gradients = self.gradientKerasFunc(inp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3565, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1470, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'softmax_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[{{node softmax_target}}]]
```

So something is also wrong in this case...

Python 3.5, Windows 7 x64

Comment: I used TF 2.0. I had similar error. It appeared to be problem  with the way I build my model. i fixed it though. You can post your entire  model code if you want  someone to have a look at it. More than bug, i guess it is something you might have been doing wrong.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7, no, but I have found combination that works for some reason, I will add answer now

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found solution, but have found workaround, it is like this

```
def get_tensor_array_element(x):
    def f(X):                               # Here we have e.g. np.ones([4])
        return X[x : x + 1]

    def g(input_shape):
        output_shape = list(input_shape)    # Here - e.g. (None, 4)
        output_shape[-1] = 1
        return tuple(output_shape)

    return Lambda(f, output_shape=lambda input_shape: g(input_shape))


towerWeightsKerasVar = tf.compat.v1.Variable(np.ones([towerCount]),
             dtype=tf.float32, name='tower_weights')
towerWeightsKerasVar._trainable = False    # "Doesn't help against Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled."
towerWeights = Input(shape=(towerCount, ), tensor=towerWeightsKerasVar)
    # Looks like input, should be declared in model's input, but (if the tensor parameter is present)
    # should not be supplied to the net (in model.fit and so on)
...
conv = Multiply()([conv, get_tensor_array_element(i)(towerWeights)])
```